# How to remove a data from a list after it has been selected

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Form with 2 TextBox.  I'm using randomize method to pick up a certain Country based on column D.  I want to be able to remove the selected Country after it has been selected. In my screenshot, we'll notice that the country Nigeria has been assigned to Jessie.

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim randomCtry As Long

Randomize

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
DoEvents

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'With txtDestination
'    .Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Int((LastRow - 1) * Rnd + 2))
'
'End With


Set randomCtry = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Int((LastRow - 1) * Rnd + 2))
txtDestination.Text = randomCtry.Text
randomCtry.Delete Shift:=xlUp ' <-- remove the selected country from the list


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
DoEvents


With Sheet1

        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

        .Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(txtMilitary.Text, txtDestination.Text)

        End With


        On Error Resume Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to remove permanently the selected country form the list in column D?

Comment: Not really remove. What I really want is once that Army return then the country will be back in the list..something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the country that is already assigned, permanently from column D, you can do it like this:

```
   dim randomCtry as Range
   set randomCtry = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Int((LastRow - 1) * Rnd + 2))
   txtDestination.Text = randomCtry.Text
   randomCtry.Delete Shift:=xlUp ' <-- remove the selected country from the list
```

The above code replaces the bloc of your code `With txtDestination ...End With`

Comment: Thank you..I don'k know where to put the line of code.

Comment: @KurtMatthew As I said in the last sentence, it replaces the `With - End with` bloc, Notice that it deletes permanently the selected country from column D. but at any moment later in your application it's easy to copy back the countries from column B to column D.

Comment: I edit my code above but I'm giving getting an error message object not found. Please see the code again.

Comment: @KurtMatthew yeah sorry, `dim randomCtry as Range` not `As Long`.

Comment: A.S.H you don't have to say sorry Sir/Ma'am..I owe this from you and you really do it in a very quick manner.. Thank you somuch..